# TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined

Tags: javascript

I don't quite understand why the following code doesn't work. Is this some kind of restriction on the *call* function? The browser I'm using to run this code is *Mozilla Firefox*.

```
"use strict";

var object = {
    foo : "test",
      m : function() {
              console.log(this.foo);
          }
};

var bar = object.m.call;
bar(object); // TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined
```

That was just an example to address a bigger, real-world issue. Consider the following:

```
setInterval(object.m.call, 2000, object);
```

I'd say, to me, this very much sounds like quite a logical way to do it, but obviously that statement is not going to work because of that *TypeError*.

Comment: You'd need to `bind` `call` to `m`.

Comment: Chrome 46 throws 'TypeError: bar is not a function'.

Comment: You're misusing `call`.  What you're looking for is `var bar = object.m.bind(object);`  Then, `bar();`

Comment: `Function.prototype.call` is an internal method exposed by the runtime. It expects a target. Invoking it without a target (`undefined` in this case because you are in strict mode), results in behavior peculiar to that JS engine's implementation.

Comment: What you actually want is `setInterval(object.m.bind(object), 2000);`. There is no reason to use `call` at all. See also [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)